# How to modify state of a parent component from a child component which is a custom form I wrote. This might also effect other children of the parent

Tags: reactjs, components, react-hooks, state, react-component

I wrote a custom form component called `SingleFilterContainer`

Within the parent component called `FiltersContainer`, I initialize a state `filters` which has an array of a single filter initially and respective `setFilters` function to modify the array of filters. And also has a button to add a filter. And in the render function I use `filters.map` to render `SingleFilterContainer` component multiple times. So far this works. But I want to add a delete filter button. I put this inside the `SingleFilterContainer`. When I click this it should update the state `filters` in the parent component and delete the ith filter and render the rest of the filters normally. Or render the whole map of filters again.

I'm new to react and hooks, and I feel like I'm missing something. I'm at it for the past three days and I'm a little bit lost.

Here is the sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/editing-filters-j2qrp

I feel like how I'm handling state is completely wrong. And maybe I should use redux? But I want the `SingleFilterContainer` to be like an ephemeral form. Or should the delete filter button be within the parent component? and repeat it using map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR [Fixed fork](https://codesandbox.io/s/editing-filters-sy52i)

The problem in your code is that you call the function on render `onClick={handleDeleteFilter(i)}` the `onClick` expects a reference to a function, but if you want this code to work, then the method that you are passing from the parent to the child needs to return a function also.

Then your `handleDeleteFilter` will look like this:

```
function handleDeleteFilter(i) {
  return function() {
     filters.splice(i, i + 1);
     setFilters(filters => filters);
  }
}
```

Also in your case you don't need to pass `i + 1` into `splice` as the second argument, as the second argument is the amount of items to remove. Which in your case is just 1. [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

You pass the `i` to the first function and the second one will see it due to closure.

And then to the removing of an element.

Mutating the state is bad practice, so you can have a local variable with a copy of the state, which you can manipulate and then update the state. That way you can use whatever you want, but on the local variable.

So your updated `handleDeleteFilter` would look like

```
function handleDeleteFilter(i) {
  return function() {
      const clone = [...filters]
      clone.splice(i, 1);
      setFilters(clone);
  }
}
```

or with `.filter`

```
function handleDeleteFilter(i) {
  return function() {
      const clone = filters.filter((item, index) => index !== i)
      setFilters(clone);
  }
}
```

this way you don't need a new variable as `.filter` returns a new array. [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Thank you so much. Now I'm able to delete individual filter properly. But I'm really unhappy with how my code still looks. Am I coding the react way? With how I'm managing the state. I needed to use filter to functionally delete a filter, and then return a function in the onclick handler i'm passing.

Comment: I'd split it a bit more. The `SingleFilterContainer` is a bit large TBH. You can split individual filters, so that they have each own state, then the code will be more readable.

Comment: Be careful with the way you copy arrays (JSON.parse/stringify). It might fail you and you won't know where.

Comment: I think there are still some bugs in my code, even in your fork, when I'm deletings sometiems, its behaving weirdly. Say I have 3 filters, and deleted the 2nd filter. its deleting the 3rd filter

Comment: The filters object is getting modified properly, but the rendered child components are not getting rendered according to the filters state. do I have to use `useEffect`?

Comment: That's where you should use `key`. React checks if the array has changed. And you added the `key` as the index, that's why it's not rendering again. If you add some sort of ID to the object, and pass it to the `key` prop - it should work. And passing index as `key` is a bad practice too ( this is exactly why)

Comment: Here you go: https://epicreact.dev/ or https://frontendmasters.com/

Frontendmasters is really great, and worth it's money.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my [fork](https://codesandbox.io/s/editing-filters-k0dg4?file=/src/FiltersContainer.js:425-533).

The following is my changes.

```
  function handleDeleteFilter(i) {
    setFilters(filters => filters.filter((e, index) => index !== i));
  }
```

Important notes:

1. Ideally, you need to assign an `id` property for each item in the array instead of comparing by index.
2. Don't directly mutate the state. `.splice` directly mutates the state. Learn to use `.map`, `.filter` & `.reduce` array functions

Comment: I uncommented the deleteButton code in the child component, its behaving weirdly. Now I'm not able to add a filter. Here is the fork https://codesandbox.io/s/editing-filters-rnhnt

Comment: handleDeleteFilter has to return a function it seems. llllke the other answer mentions. and now its working.